# Python 2.7 unable to load DLL (VC2017 built) from cmd.exe Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, powershell, cmd

Good day! I've just faced a very tricky issue which I can hardly explain and resolve.

I have a dll compiled in VC 2017. This dll is basically a python module: SWIG wrapper was used to create the interfaces. So at a given folder I have the following files:

- python.exe
- python27.dll
- TestLib.dll
- TestLib.pyd
- test_lib.py
- load.py

File test_lib.py is the interface generated by SWIG.

My "load.py" script:

```
from test_lib import *
```

Command I execute in shell:

```
python.exe load.py
```

---

### Tests

If I run this command in cmd.exe as a regular user, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "load.py", line 1, in <module>
    from test_lib import *
  File "test_lib.py", line 28, in <module>
    TestLib = swig_import_helper()
  File "test_lib.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('TestLib', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

It seems that either Windows or Python is unable to load the module. I checked with Dependency Walker the dll dependencies and everything seems to be OK.

Now the strange things start.

If I execute the same command in cmd.exe with Administrative privilege, it works!

If I execute the same command in Powershell as a regular user, it works once again!

---

### Analysis

I took Process Monitor tool and analyzed each of these three calls.

1. [cmd.exe + regular user](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vgntr66d10oohe9/call1_cmd.exe_regular_user.txt?dl=0)
2. [cmd.exe + admin or powershell.exe + regular user](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ew2iyie969c9rwa/call2_cmd.exe_admin_user.txt?dl=0)

Yes, cmd+admin and powershell+regular exhibit the same behavior. You may see that in all of the three calls after command QueryAllInformationFile gets BUFFER OVERFLOW status, Windows starts searching the library in different locations (*why???*).

In the last two calls after 2 alternative paths have been checked (**C:\MyCompany\Project\Project\Project\Project\Bin\Win32\TestLib.pyd** and **C:\Project\Bin\Win32\TestLib.pyd**), Windows goes back to the initial location **C:\MyCompany\Project\Project\Project\bin\Win32\TestLib.pyd** and finally starts loading the DLL.

However, cmd.exe with regular user privileges behaves in a different way. Windows tries a bunch of directories and it seems at the end terminates the process since consideres that the library has not been found. (*why???*)

Finally if I do a small trick and besides its original location additionally copy my library to **C:\MyCompany\Project\Project\Project\Project\Bin\Win32\TestLib.pyd** cmd.exe with regular user privileges runs with no error! This is ridiculous.

---

### Questions

1. What the hell is happening with this call (cmd.exe + regular user)?
2. How can I fix it?
3. Why does Windows try to search my library in so many locations, though it detects it in the initially specified location from the very first step?

Comment: you could try to print `PYTHONPATH` in all 3 cases. I see some suspect `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex` path that isn't in successful attempt

Comment: @Jean-François-Fabre Thank you for reply! I'll check PYTHONPATH. That directory (I have Miktex installed on my machine), as well as the others, seems coming from my Windows PATH variable and is not the only unsuccessful attempt.

Comment: PATH could also be the culprit. Let me write an answer, and you'll tell me.